# How to replicate curved lines connecting iOS 14 iMessage replies using UIKit?

Tags: swift, uikit, ios14, imessage, reply

In iOS 14, iMessage replies were introduced. Whenever a message is sent as a reply, a curved connecting line is formed. This connecting line is curved and animates, changes shape, and even "loops" as more replies are sent.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how these lines are formed? Are they part of the individual message cells (it doesn't seem so)? I'd like to recreate them but don't know where to start.